# Find name of the last cell with data in a row

Tags: excel, find, cell, excel-2008

I've searched for an answer, but it seems that I can only find VBA-based solutions, which appear no longer be an option in Excel 2008.

I'm trying to return the name of the last cell in a row that contains data. It looks like this:

```
+===========================================================+
                 A      /  B  /  C  /  D  /  E  (columns)
+===========================================================+
1         || [Formula] /  3  /  4  /  5  / [blank]
2         || [Formula] /  7  /  8  / [blank] / [blank]
3         || [Formula] /  9  / 10 / 11 / 12
(rows)
+===========================================================+
```

and the end result would look like this:

```
+===========================================================+
             A   /  B  /  C  /  D  /  E  (columns)
+===========================================================+
1         || D1 /  3  /  4  /  5  / 
2         || C2 /  7  /  8  /     / 
3         || E3 /  9  / 10 / 11 / 12
(rows)
+===========================================================+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your data is sorted from left to right.
If it is, you could start with something like `=MATCH(MAX(C4:K4);C4:K4)` to retrieve the column index of the last cell (max) of the row. From there, it's easy to buid the address:
`=ADDRESS(ROW();MATCH(MAX(C1:K1);C1:K1);4)`

---

Edit: combining ADDRESS with COUNT or COUNTA (great idea from Dustin Geile) does not require the items to be sorted:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()+COUNT(B1:Z1);4)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=CHAR(COUNTA(B1:ZZ1) + 65) & ROW()
```

Comment: This solution doesn't actually return the correct column.  It's off by 1... I would up using: =CELL("address",INDEX(B21:IV21,MATCH(2,INDEX(1/(B21:IV21<>""),0))))

Answer (score 0):

You can try this arrayformula:

```
{=ADDRESS(ROW(B2),MAX(IF(ISEMPTY(B2:H2),0,COLUMN(B2:H2))))}
```

Validate with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the last cell with data, you can write a quick function and place it in a VBA module in your workbook.

Public Function LastCell(inRange as Range)
   LastCell = inRange.End(XlToRight).Address
End Function

Or just omit the '.Address' if you want to get a range object pointing to the cell.

You can then use it in a formula like...

=LastCell(A1)

Regards
Ray

Comment: The OP is using Excel 2008 (Mac) - there's no VBA available.